# Function call for a state machine state needs to return function pointer of same type

Tags: c++, function-pointers, state-machine

I am coding a state machine in Visual C++ '22 representing each state as a function with each state determining and returning a function pointer to its next state.  While my code seems correct based on syntax checking by the editor, and while it works if a remove the function pointer parameter from the function call (can no longer construct a state machine), actual compilation gives me a syntax error; and a whole bunch of knock on errors.  Is this a compiler bug or am I just coding this wrong?

Here is my cut down test code.

```
typedef void (*myfnptr)(__int64& val, myfnptr& nextState);

void aFn(__int64& val, myfnptr& nextState )
{
    val = 7;
    nextState = &bFn;
}

void bFn(__int64& val, myfnptr& nextState)
{
    val = 9;
    nextState = &aFn;
 }

int main()
{
    __int64 val;
    myfnptr fn = &aFn;
    myfnptr nextState;
    fn(val, nextState);
    nextState(val, nextState);
}
```

And the error for the "typedef" line
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'myfnptr' ...

I'm assuming that the problem is due to the circularity of the definition in the typedef, but I can see no way to code around this circularity, and such a definition is important to defining a state machine where the states are implemented as functions and passed as function pointers rather than using e.g a switch statement and an enum at the state machine higher level.

Comment: 1st rule: There's almost never a compiler bug, but your code is wrong.

Comment: **C2061 syntax error: identifier 'myfnptr'...** Don't abbreviate the errors, always post full error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite types can't be infinitely deeply nested in C++ and a `typedef` doesn't create a new type but only aliases another. So you can't write a function type that takes a `typedef`ed alias to itself as part of a parameter, which would cause the type to infinitely recurse and nest on itself.

Instead form an actually new distinct type by writing a class to wrap your function pointer as a member. This class type can then be used as parameter in a function type:

```
struct NextState;

typedef void (*myfnptr)(__int64& val, NextState& nextState);
// or, probably easier to read:
// using myfnptr = void (*)(__int64&, NextState&);

struct NextState {
    myfnptr ptr;

    // A constructor so that you can assign/initialize
    // with a raw function pointer directly.
    // Without it you need to assign explicitly to
    // nextState.ptr or use brace initialization/assignment.
    NextState(myfnptr ptr_) : ptr(ptr_) {};

    // A conversion function to the raw pointer type,
    // so that nextState can be called directly as
    // nextState(/*...*/)
    // Without it you need to write nextState.ptr(/*...*/).
    operator myfnptr() { return ptr; }
};

void aFn(__int64& val, NextState& nextState )
{
    val = 7;
    nextState = &bFn;
}

void bFn(__int64& val, NextState& nextState)
{
    val = 9;
    nextState = &aFn;
 }

int main()
{
    __int64 val;
    NextState nextState = &aFn;
    // no need for `fn` here
    nextState(val, nextState);
    nextState(val, nextState);
}
```

Consider using `std::int64_t` instead of `__int64`. The former is (since C++11) standardized and will give you an exactly 64bit wide signed integer type on all C++ implementations that support such a type, while `__int64` is compiler-specific.

---

(I am not commenting on whether the design choice for the state machine is a good one, since that seems out of scope. There are many other ways of doing it that may be better approaches.)

Comment: Needs a quick fix: `NextState` has no call operator.

Comment: @user4581301 Fixed in a slightly different form.

Comment: Works for me. Should compile down to the same thing.